# How to populate a trie in C?

Tags: c, struct, trie

I'm trying to write a program that takes words and creates a trie with each node of the trie being a struct containing one single character.

I have a function that parses a char* into words (assume that char* contains only lowercase letters).  As each word is taken from the char* it is passed to the function `addWordOccurrence(const char* word, const int wordLength, struct tNode root)`.  The `addWordOccurrence()` is supposed to check if the first letter of the word is in `root.branches[i]` as i increments in a loop checking every possible index of `root.branches` (which is 0-25 for all of the lowercase letters of the alphabet).  If the first letter is not in `root.branches` a new struct `tNode` is created containing the new letter.  Then continues on to the second letter of the word comparing it to the branches of the newly made struct `tNode` and so on...

The first word we have tried is "doctor" and my trie takes the first letter 'd' and adds it to the `root.branches[0]` then takes the 'o' and adds it to the `root.branches[0].branches[0]`, which is correct.  But then it adds the 'd' in doctor to the next 17 indexes of its branches (so `root.branches[0].branches[1] through [18]`), which is not supposed to be the case. Please help!

```
struct tNode{
  char c;
  int occurrences;
  struct tNode *branches;
};

int addWordOccurrence(const char* word, const int wordLength, struct tNode root){
//declare fields
int counter, i,k,firstNull;
counter = 0;
while(1){
  if(counter >= wordLength){
    break;
  }
  //traverse through the word letter by letter
  for(i=0; i<wordLength; i++){
    //compare each letter to the branches of root until the letter is found or first null space
    for(k=0; k<26; k++){
    //if the letter is a branch already set root to the struct of that letter in branches
       if(root.branches[k].c == word[i]){
          root = root.branches[k];
          break;
       }
    }
    //the current letter of the word is not in branches
    //go through branches to find position to add the new tNode
    for(firstNull=0; firstNull<26; firstNull++){
       //set firstNull equal to the index of the first null value in branches
       if(root.branches[firstNull].c  <  'a' || root.branches[firstNull].c > 'z' ){
          break;
       }
    }
    //add a new node to branches
    root.branches[firstNull].c = word[i];
    root.branches[firstNull].occurrences = 0;
    root.branches[firstNull].branches = malloc(sizeof(struct tNode) * 26);
    if(counter != wordLength){
       root = root.branches[firstNull];
    }
    counter++;
    if(counter == wordLength-2){
       root.occurrences++;
    }
 }
}
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think the first `break` is doing?  My strong bet is that it's not doing that.

Comment: Originally the root.occurrences++ at the end of the while loop was outside of the while, so that after the last letter of the word was read it would increment the 'r' (if the word was 'doctor') tNode.occurrences of the last letter added, but when I was debugging it the value of tNode.occurrence was 0 when it should have been 1, so the break was to exit the while loop...I've changed it so many times, I'm going crazy looking at it, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

A bunch of problems with your implementation:

1. This is a strange design of a trie with having a random arrangement of the alphabet. Having to do a linear search of the letter you want on each level defeats the purpose of doing a trie in the first place.
2. When you do `root = root.branches[k];` you are creating a copy of the variable. Now it might happen to work for you in this case due to accessing things through pointers but it is really just asking for trouble.
3. When you allocate a node in the loop you don't initialize it which means it is filled with junk/unknown data and cause issues.
4. Your implementation is needlessly complex, like your outer `while (1)` loop.

For a very simple trie I would do something like:

```
struct tNode {
  bool isWord;
  struct tNode *branches[26];
};

void addWordOccurrence (const char* word, const int wordLength, struct tNode* pRoot) {
   int i;
   int nodeIndex;
   tNode* pCurrentNode = pRoot;

   for (i = 0; i < wordLength; ++i)
   {
       nodeIndex = tolower(word[i]) - 'a'; 

       if (nodeIndex >= 0 && nodeIndex <= 25)
       {
            if (pCurrentNode->branches[nodeIndex] == NULL)
            {
                pCurrentNode->branches[nodeIndex] = calloc(1, sizeof(tNode));
            }

            pCurrentNode = pCurrentNode->branches[nodeIndex];
       }
   }

   pCurrentNode->isWord = true;
}
```

You could use `struct tNode *branches;` but it really just adds another allocation step that you don't really need. You use the ASCII value of the characters to assign `branches[0]` to 'a' and `branches[25]` to 'z'...no need to search for a "free" spot which would really kill the trie's performance. Finally, you need a terminator like `isWord` in order to know that "doctor" is a word while "docto" is not.